# Vue.JS Как реализовать вывод checkbox'a статична а не из массива

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

Интересует такой момент, с VueJS только начинаю знакомиться.
Помогите сделать вывод checkbox из html а не из массива.

В моем случае, выборка input=radio работает по средствам html, есть на пример 3 radio которые прописаны в html
И есть допустим 4 checkbox'a но они прописаны в массиве и выводятся циклом
КАК сделать checkbox'ы вывод как и radio из html ?

Вот мой код:

```js
   var app = new Vue({
      el: '.app',
      data: {
        user: {},
        totalAges: 0,
          logins:[
              {name:'Jhon', age:11, price:1000},
              {name:'Richard', age:12, price:2000},
              {name:'Robert', age:13, price:3000},
              {name:'Jack', age:14, price:4000}
          ],
          selectedLogins:[],
      },
      methods: {
        clearRadio() {
          this.user = {},
          this.sumTotalAge();
        },
        sumTotalAge(){
          this.totalAges = this.selectedLogins.reduce((acc,item) => acc += item.age, 0) + (this.user.age ? this.user.age : 0);
        }
      },
    });
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div class="row app">
  <div class="col-6">
    <div class="border p-3 h-100">
      <div class="font-weight-bold pt-2">Коробка</div>

      <input type="radio" v-bind:value="{name:'Tom', age:22}" v-model="user" v-on:change="sumTotalAge">
      <label>Tom</label>
      <br>
      <input type="radio" v-bind:value="{name:'Bob', age:25}" v-model="user" v-on:change="sumTotalAge">
      <label>Bob</label>
      <br>
      <input type="radio" v-bind:value="{name:'Sam', age:28}" v-model="user" v-on:change="sumTotalAge">
      <label>Sam</label>
      <br>

      <div class="font-weight-bold pt-2">Продукты</div>
      <template v-for="login in logins">
          <input type="checkbox" v-bind:value="login" v-model="selectedLogins" v-on:change="sumTotalAge">
          <label>{{login.name}}</label><br>
      </template>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-6">
    <div class="border p-3 h-100">
      <ul class="nav flex-column">
        <li v-if="user.name" class="nav-link">{{user.name}} {{user.age}}
          <button class="btn btn-sm py-0 btn-danger" @click="clearRadio">x</button>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-link" v-for="login in selectedLogins">{{login.name}} - {{login.age}} - {{login.price}}
          <input type="checkbox" v-bind:value="login" v-model="selectedLogins" v-on:change="sumTotalAge">
        </li>
      </ul>

      <hr>
      <span class="pl-3">Total age: {{ totalAges }}</span>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Так же в редакторе: https://jsfiddle.net/synapse3/7tw0m6gy/3/

Мне нужно реализовать checkbox'ы примерно так же как и radio, что бы я значение вписывал в html в не массив

Помогите пожалуйста кодом.
Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возьмите и выведите как:

```
 <input id="Jhon" type="checkbox" v-bind:value="{
    name: 'Jhon',
    age: 11,
    price: 1000
  }" v-model="selectedLogins" v-on:change="sumTotalAge">
  <label for="Jhon">Jhon</label><br>
  <input id="Richard" type="checkbox" v-bind:value="{
    name: 'Richard',
    age: 12,
    price: 2000
  }" v-model="selectedLogins" v-on:change="sumTotalAge">
  <label for="Richard">Richard</label><br>
  <input id="Robert" type="checkbox" v-bind:value="{
    name: 'Robert',
    age: 13,
    price: 3000
  }" v-model="selectedLogins" v-on:change="sumTotalAge">
  <label for="Robert">Robert</label><br>
  <input id="Jack" type="checkbox" v-bind:value="{
    name: 'Jack',
    age: 14,
    price: 4000
  }" v-model="selectedLogins" v-on:change="sumTotalAge">
  <label for="Jack">Jack</label><br>
```

**id="Jhon"** - для привязки `label` к `checkbox`;

**type="checkbox"** - тип поля ввода HTML;

**v-bind:value="{
name: 'Jhon',
age: 11,
price: 1000
}"** - присваиваете значению поля ввода объект с данными;

**v-model="selectedLogins"** - обеспечиваете двунаправленное связывание данных с элементом формы `checkbox`

**v-on:change="sumTotalAge"** - вешаете обработчик на событие

Рабочий пример:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '.app',
  data: {
    user: {},
    totalAges: 0,
    selectedLogins: [],
  },
  methods: {
    clearRadio() {
      this.user = {},
        this.sumTotalAge();
    },
    sumTotalAge() {
      this.totalAges = this.selectedLogins.reduce((acc, item) => acc += item.age, 0) + (this.user.age ? this.user.age : 0);
    }
  },
});
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>

<div class="row app">
  <div class="col-6">
    <div class="border p-3 h-100">
      <div class="font-weight-bold pt-2">Коробка</div>

      <input id="Tom" type="radio" v-bind:value="{name:'Tom', age:22}" v-model="user" v-on:change="sumTotalAge">
      <label for="Tom">Tom</label>
      <br>
      <input id="Bob" type="radio" v-bind:value="{name:'Bob', age:25}" v-model="user" v-on:change="sumTotalAge">
      <label for="Bob">Bob</label>
      <br>
      <input id="Sam" type="radio" v-bind:value="{name:'Sam', age:28}" v-model="user" v-on:change="sumTotalAge">
      <label for="Sam">Sam</label>
      <br>

      <div class="font-weight-bold pt-2">Продукты</div>
      <input id="Jhon" type="checkbox" v-bind:value="{
        name: 'Jhon',
        age: 11,
        price: 1000
      }" v-model="selectedLogins" v-on:change="sumTotalAge">
      <label for="Jhon">Jhon</label><br>
      <input id="Richard" type="checkbox" v-bind:value="{
        name: 'Richard',
        age: 12,
        price: 2000
      }" v-model="selectedLogins" v-on:change="sumTotalAge">
      <label for="Richard">Richard</label><br>
      <input id="Robert" type="checkbox" v-bind:value="{
        name: 'Robert',
        age: 13,
        price: 3000
      }" v-model="selectedLogins" v-on:change="sumTotalAge">
      <label for="Robert">Robert</label><br>
      <input id="Jack" type="checkbox" v-bind:value="{
        name: 'Jack',
        age: 14,
        price: 4000
      }" v-model="selectedLogins" v-on:change="sumTotalAge">
      <label for="Jack">Jack</label><br>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-6">
    <div class="border p-3 h-100">
      <ul class="nav flex-column">
        <li v-if="user.name" class="nav-link">{{user.name}} {{user.age}}
          <button class="btn btn-sm py-0 btn-danger" @click="clearRadio">x</button>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-link" v-for="login in selectedLogins">{{login.name}} - {{login.age}} - {{login.price}}
          <input type="checkbox" v-bind:value="login" v-model="selectedLogins" v-on:change="sumTotalAge">
        </li>
      </ul>

      <hr>
      <span class="pl-3">Total age: {{ totalAges }}</span>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```